# Mysql reject insert if true

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I am currently trying to write some MySQL which will reject an insert statement on a table if the date inserted is the past

`CREATE TRIGGER reject_past_date_entry
  BEFORE INSERT ON bookings FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN 
    IF (NEW.date <= CURDATE()) THEN
    //Reject insert statement
    END IF
END $$`

Could someone please take a look at what I should be writing here, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: checkout signal for mysql trigger and using signal you can raise an user defined error message and the insert will be rejected.

Comment: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;




CREATE VIEW future_booking
AS
 SELECT code, date, room
    FROM booking
    WHERE date >= CURDATE();
   
   DELIMITER $$
    
CREATE TRIGGER reject_past_bookings
BEFORE INSERT ON bookings FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN 
    IF (NEW.date <= CURDATE()) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ERROR';
    ELSE IF;
    
    DELIMITER ;
    
    INSERT INTO bookings (date)
    VALUES ('2002.01.01');
    
SELECT *
FROM session;